# HTML CSS fixed element only when body reaches a particular point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure what the method is or how its achieved. But I'm interested in knowing about it to possibly use it in an upcoming project. What I am referring to is when a block element is at a particular X/Y axis it seems it stops acting as though it were a fixed position element otherwise the element acts as a fixed position element.

I most commonly see this with navigation, where the header and footer are large and the element will stop acting as a fixed element when it reaches the bottom of the header or top of the footer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){    
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250){ 
        $('#top').css('position','fixed'); 
    }
    else{
        $('#top').css('position','static');
    }
});
```

A better approach would be,

```
$(window).scroll(function(){    
    var top =  $('#top'); 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250){
        if(top.css('position') !== 'fixed'){ 
            top.css('position','fixed'); 
        }
    }
    else{
        if(top.css('position') !== 'static'){
            top.css('position','static');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**There are plugins** that will do this for you; this is one I've used before: [link](http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/sticky-sidebar-jquery-plugin/) with relative success. Has great examples, too.

But **if you want to do it yourself**, it's not too difficult. The concept is slightly convoluted; if you change something's `position` to `fixed`, then it will not take up space, as it would if it was `static`.

When I came across this issue, I created a second item in the same place (or not, depending where you want it to appear), which is invisible. Then you implement a load/scroll event that checks if the window's `scrollTop` is greater than the `top` coordinate of the non-fixed object. If it is, show the fixed object.

Something like this:

```
$("#yourObject").each(function() { // The ID should be the FIXED object.
    var $me = $(this);
    var $heightRival = $("#anotherObject"); // This ID should be the non-fixed object.
    $me.hide(); // Hide your fixed div.
    $(window).bind("load scroll",function() {
        var offset = $heightRival.offset(); // Get the document offset of the base object.
        var height = $heightRival.outerHeight(); // Get the height of the base object.
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top+height)
            $target.show(); // Can be a fade in, slide in, whatever.
        else
            $target.hide(); // Can be a fade out, etc.
    });
});
```

This is just a rudimentary code but it should set you on the right track.

Comment: Ahh the concepts JavaScript based, I always thought it was CSS/HTML based somehow. This gives me great insight, on the whole matter. Very cool, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this plugin, or the others like it: http://www.orangecoat.com/stickyscroll